# ClamD Service Unable to Start [RHEL9]

Tags: systemd, rhel, alma-linux, clamav

I am currently following this [guide](https://linux.how2shout.com/install-clamav-on-rocky-linux-8-almalinux/) on setting up `ClamAV` on my `AlmaLinux 9.3` machine however at **Step 11** I cannot start the `clamd@service` and wanted to know if anyone else has also had this issue as I cannot find much from other sources.

```
[root@localhost tester]# sudo systemctl status clamd@service
× clamd@service.service - clamd scanner (service) daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-12-28 12:08:15 GMT; 3min 26s ago
       Docs: man:clamd(8)
             man:clamd.conf(5)
             https://www.clamav.net/documents/
    Process: 6728 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/clamd -c /etc/clamd.d/service.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 3ms

Dec 28 12:08:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 28 12:08:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped clamd scanner (service) daemon.
Dec 28 12:08:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 28 12:08:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 12:08:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start clamd scanner (service) daemon.
```

I executed the following command as per the Terminal output recommended:

`$ journalctl -xeu clamd@service.service`

```
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit clamd@service.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start clamd scanner (service) daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit clamd@service.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit clamd@service.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 7444 and the job result is failed.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit clamd@service.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped clamd scanner (service) daemon.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit clamd@service.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit clamd@service.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 7568 and the job result is done.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: clamd@service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit clamd@service.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 12:45:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start clamd scanner (service) daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit clamd@service.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit clamd@service.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 7568 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still new to all of this, where would the logs be located? Would be it be something like `/var/log/`?

Comment: Yes. You can find out which log file by using Google rather than waiting for it here. If you're going to use Linux or any other Unix-like OS, you'll need to become familiar with logs.

Comment: Yes, slowly but surely I hope to familiarise myself with log files and how they are handled in Linux. I tried to Google the issue, but I wasn't able to find anything concrete hence I tried my luck here.

Comment: Clamd is a tool for detectting Windows viruses, in email. Is this (serving email to Windows users) your use case, or are you wasting time?

Comment: @waltinator I was looking for an antivirus package for my Linux environment and ClamAV is supposedly the defacto software. I'm not serving email or running any kind of mail server currently.

Comment: Try running `sudo /usr/sbin/clamd --debug -c /etc/clamd.d/service.conf` from the terminal. Exit code 1 mostly is a "operation not permitted", might be a selinux issue, maybe you get more information when calling directly.

Comment: @stoney thank you for your input. I executed your command and unfortunately got: `ERROR: Can't open/parse the config file /etc/clamd.d/service.conf`

Comment: the service.conf probably doesn't exist. Your example talks about a scan.conf, check the name (probably also another file in there)

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `/etc/clamd.d/scan.conf` to `/etc/clamd.d/service.conf` and make the modifications in step 11 to that file.

The systemd unit they are calling has an instance name, `@`, which is passed to a variable as the unit and referenced as `%i`. So, when you are trying to call `systemctl start clamd@service`, it is referencing `/etc/clamd.d/service.conf` per the unit file, which does not exist.

If we create the configuration file the unit is looking for, it should start.

For reference, the unit file is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@.service`